# what should I set in HTTP_HOST environment variable inside a docker for appengine task queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker

Trying to run a worker to push and pull from an appengine `pushqueue`

```
import os, sys

test_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

paths = [
    '/../../google_appengine',
]

for path in paths:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(test_directory + path))


from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```

Getting the following :

> WARNING:root:The HTTP_HOST environment variable was not set, but is required to determine the correct value for the `Task.target' property. Please update your unit tests to specify a correct value for this environment variable.

how do I set it ?

I think, getting this error since I'm running from a docker, before I ran this script with a
`runtime: python27`

Comment: What is the command that you use to start the docker? And your base image, please?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that an environment variable `HTTP_HOST` be passed in `docker run` command.

It can be done by adding something like  `-e HTTP_HOST=localhost`. Of course, you can change the value in place of `localhost`.

Here is an example of `docker run` command with environment variable.

```
$ docker run -itd -e HTTP_HOST=l92.168.10.1 ubuntu
7bfdf649ca666954167f6093fba8ff094f615aac0b497c5c506eb89b0fa19803
```

Check the docker container running, take the name:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7bfdf649ca66        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         6 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            big_lumiere
```

Check the environment vairable is passed to container:

```
docker exec -it big_lumiere bash
root@7bfdf649ca66:/# echo $HTTP_HOST
l92.168.10.1
```

So, make sure you pass the `HTTP_HOST` with appropriate value in `docker run` command to resolve the issue.

Comment: what is `l92.168.10.1`? where did you find it ?

Comment: that was just an example value. You may replace it like I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: yes, I got that. but how did you find that value ? how will I find out what to put that? what does value mean ? how does it effect the `taskqueue `

Comment: If you are running on your localhost, just pass it `localhost` and see if that helps.

Comment: it doesn't . `assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "taskqueue"`

Comment: @WebQube, sorry, i am not sure how are you using it or where do you need to use. All I mentioned was how you can pass the environment variable overriden while running `docker run` command.